# ffmpeg smooth video upscaling

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've got some old videos in 320x240 that I want to upscale to 640x480

DISCLAIMER: *I know upscaling always ruins quality.*

My problem is that, "regular" upscaling options in ffmpeg(-s or scale filter) always give much worse results comparing to manual resizing in any media player when watching video(Resize 2:1 option in Ubuntu's Movie Player for example). So, it's clear that there are *better* algorithms, which are used by the player to upscale the video. I just dont know how ta make ffmpeg use them, I'm newbie video converter :-) I need your help with converting options for ffmpeg for smooth as possible upscale.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it look ok if you upscale with ffplay? `ffplay input.mp4 -vf scale=640:-1`. That way you can determine if the scaling or the re-encoding is the issue.